# Extract multiple elements from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello Good People of Stackoverflow
I have a sql column that is made up of autogenerated strings. I need to extract the number values from this string to insert into new columns to be used for reference. 've never had to manipulate a string like this before but I'd really appreciate any help I can get.
I have made an excel mock-up of what I want - the very left "text" column is the one I want to be reduced to the columns that follow. Note I have put the string in SQL '', they are not part of the string:

```
Text Column                                                                                                                                                     ReserveFrom  ReserveTo  PaymentFrom   paymentTo
'Scheme ELS updated. Reserve Authority Level changed from: 11000000.00 to: 8000000.00.'                                                                           11000000    8000000 
'Scheme CNST updated. Payment Authority Level changed from: 8000000.00 to: 10000000.00. Reserve Authority Level changed from: 8000000.00 to: 10000000.00.'        11000000    8000000     11000000     8000000
'Scheme ELS updated. Payment Authority Level changed from: 350000.00 to: 100000.00. '                                                                                                       350000      100000
```

These are the three permutations of the text column.

Comment: Can you please post expected output

Comment: A lot of `substring` manipulation based on `charindex` values on some `where column like '%%'` query results is what you should be looking at.

Comment: Hello. The expected output is the four coulumns: ReserveFrom,ReserveTo,PaymentFrom and PaymentTo. I need the results in these columns to be derived from the "Text Column" cvalues in red.

Comment: You are going to have to use a combination of substring and charindex as suggested already. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using both subtring and charindex to extract a part of a string before but I dont have the skill to extract these numbers that are also based on the keywords (i.e. reserve or payment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #text_table (text_field varchar(250))


insert into #text_table values 
('Scheme ELS updated. Reserve Authority Level changed from: 11000000.00 to: 8000000.00.'),      
('Scheme CNST updated. Payment Authority Level changed from: 8000000.00 to: 10000000.00. Reserve Authority Level changed from: 8000000.00 to: 10000000.00.'),
('Scheme ELS updated. Payment Authority Level changed from: 350000.00 to: 100000.00.')

drop table #text_table2
select *, 
case when charindex('Reserve', text_field ,0) > 0 and charindex('Payment', text_field,0) = 0 then 'Reserve'  
     when charindex('Payment', text_field,0) > 0 and charindex('Reserve', text_field,0) = 0 then 'Payment' 
     when charindex('Payment', text_field,0) > 0 and charindex('Reserve', text_field,0) > 0 then 'Both'
     else 'N/A' end as tag,
charindex('from: ',text_field,0) as From_Index,
charindex(' to: ',text_field, charindex('from: ',text_field,0)) as to_index,
charindex('.',text_field, charindex(' to: ',text_field, charindex('from: ',text_field,0))) as dot_index
into #text_table2
from #text_table

select * 
into #simple
from #text_table2 where tag in ('Reserve','Payment')

select
substring(text_field, 0, charindex('.00. ',text_field,0)+3) as text_field
into #parse
from #text_table2 where tag = 'Both'
union
select
substring(text_field, charindex('.00. ',text_field,0)+5, charindex('.00.',text_field,charindex('.00.',text_field,0)+3)) 
from #text_table2 where tag = 'Both'

insert into #simple
select *, 
case when charindex('Reserve', text_field ,0) > 0 and charindex('Payment', text_field,0) = 0 then 'Reserve'  
     when charindex('Payment', text_field,0) > 0 and charindex('Reserve', text_field,0) = 0 then 'Payment' 
     when charindex('Payment', text_field,0) > 0 and charindex('Reserve', text_field,0) > 0 then 'Both'
     else 'N/A' end as tag,
charindex('from: ',text_field,0) as From_Index,
charindex(' to: ',text_field, charindex('from: ',text_field,0)) as to_index,
charindex('.',text_field, charindex(' to: ',text_field, charindex('from: ',text_field,0))) as dot_index
from #parse




select *,
substring(text_field, from_index+6, to_index - from_index - 6) as From_Value,
substring(text_field, to_index+4, dot_index - to_index - 1) as To_Value
from #simple
```

Comment: That's close and should get @AJCT pointed in the right direction, but doesn't account for the 'Reserve' AND 'Payment' changes in the 'CNST' scheme.

Comment: Yes, it only tags 'Reserve' for the 'Scheme CNST updated.' text, when it clearly states that both 'Reserve' and 'Payment' are changed.

Comment: updated the solution to account for two updates in one string.

Comment: @Ben - thank you! That is fantastic! String manipulation makes me want run foir the hills so I am very grateful for thyis and it'll work perfectly for what I need - Very much appreciated.